# wrong return type of a function returning the nth node of a linked list

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is a function returning the nth node of a linked list, but there is compiler error constantly saying the return type should be int. Why is that?

```
struct Node *getNthNode(struct Node* head, int index)
{
    if (head==NULL)
        return NULL;


    struct Node *current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current)
    {
        if (count == index)
            return(current);
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
```

Comment: The fragment you have shown doesn't have anything obviously wrong with it besides the bad indentation, but it's incomplete. Please post a complete test program that we can compile for ourselves and see the problem.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you post the *unedited* compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're calling the function before you've declared it, so it's defaulting to return type int. We'd have to see the whole file to know for sure. Look for all of the compiler warnings.

```
int main() {
    char* p;
    p = foo();   // Compiler assumes default int return type
    return 0;
}

char* foo() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And what are you returning if the while's condition stops being true ?

For example if you have 10 elements in your list and you pass 20 as the `index` parameter.

If you don't provide a return statement for that case, that might be the problem.